# Show user's name on Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a fan page on Facebook and I'd like to show a christmas message to the people who like the page.

The idea is:

If user likes page > say: "Merry Christmas first_name"
if user doesn't like the page > show generic message

I thought I'd be able to get the user's 1st name to display just that, since I don't want to store anything, but so far no success.

My code is:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xx',
  'secret' => 'xx',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;

if ($session) 
{
  try 
  {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } 
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
  {
    error_log($e);
  }
}

$name = $me['first_name'];
   
echo 'Merry Christmas x ' . $name . ' x ' . $uid;
```

But all it echoes is: "**Merry Christmas x x 106998XX369535**"

Where the number is the page's id, not the user's id.

Is there any way to do this without asking the user's permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer.

Just use:  to show the user's name on a TAB/Canvas app.

It also works within the Static FBML app.

Writing:

```
Merry Christmas <fb:userlink uid="loggedinuser"/>
```

Will show:

```
Merry Christmas John Smith
```

if John Smith is viewing it :)

The name will be formatted as a link, but you can style it with CSS.

Comment: "This method has been deprecated." according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/userlink

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't test it in the 1st place, but it works really well. Go figure...

Comment: Good to know, though that was expected given it was a 5 year old solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get any information about the user unless the user gives permission. Unfortunately.

But with "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" you do receive a the signed_request POST. And this way is the only way to go about it; http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas

But user still needs to authorize your application.

Comment: So what is <fb:name uid='loggedinuser' useyou='false' /> for?

Comment: Well, you can get information about a user as long as that user has has given permission to do so, in other words if a user have accepted/allowed your application.

Comment: thank you for your help. i've solved it in another way and posted the answer here. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$json  = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/$uid");
$fdata = json_decode($json);
$fname = $fdata->name;
echo 'Merry Christmas x ' . $fname . ' x ';
```